# List.add using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have read couple of articles on Linq and Func<> and understood simple examples but I cannot able to use them in day to day programming. I am keen to know what are the scenarios the LINQ or lambda expressions useful and should be used

For this code: Can I use Linq or lambda expressions

```
List<int> abundantNumbers = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 28888; i++)
     {
      if (i < pta.SumOfDivisors(i))
         {
          abundantNumbers.Add(i);
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely use LINQ in your example:

```
var abundantNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 28888)
                                .Where(i => i < pta.SumOfDivisors(i))
                                .ToList();
```

Note that it's important that you didn't just post code which *added* to list - you posted code which showed that the list was empty to start with. In other words, you're *creating* a list. If you'd merely had code which added to an existing list, I'd have used something like:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 28888).Where(i => i < pta.SumOfDivisors(i));
abundantNumbers.AddRange(query);
```

Comment: He's Jon [censored] Skeet; howd'ya think he got 434k rep?

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the answer!!!..It looks so cool..BTW is there a general scenario where LINQ can be used...or is it case by case..Thanks Again

Comment: @Ajax3.14: It's not really clear what you mean by "a general case" - almost any time you're transforming data...

Comment: Curious... can Enumerable.Range(0,28888) can be used to increment by 2... so iterates 0,2,4,6,8..28888

Comment: @Ajax3.14: No, but you could use `Enumerable.Range(0, 14444).Select(x => x * 2)`

Comment: @JonSkeet You are absolutely a god amongst men. Where did you gain all your experience ._.

Comment: @Noobgrammer: Just playing around, mostly... and lots of answering SO questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I play around a lot too, but I nearly never answer questions on SO :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with the LINQ notation, it would go like this:

```
var abundantNumbers = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 28888)
                       where i < pta.SumOfDivisors(i)
                       select i)
                      .ToList();
```